# Binding an SSL certificate to a port programmatically

Tags: .net, windows, wcf, wmi

I'm working on a self-hosted WCF service for which encrypted communications is an option.  Everything works fine when a certificate is already bound to the port as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733791.aspx).

However, I want to avoid asking the user to run a command line tool.  Is there a way the binding can be done programmatically?  Perhaps using WMI?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the way to create an HTTP.SYS namespace reservation is through the [HttpSetServiceConfiguration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364503(VS.85).aspx)() unmanaged API; so you'll need some P/Invoke for that. There's some sample code that might be useful in [one of](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163531.aspx) Keith Brown's MSDN columns.

Comment: I'm voting this up because Tomas was first and we basically said the same thing. :)

Comment: Ken Brown's article link is now dead. Can get it here though - http://web.archive.org/web/20121214083056/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163531.aspx

Answer (score 5):

I found this NuGet library that can help to programmatically bind an SSL certificate.

The question it's rather old, but I think this library could be helpful, as it was with me, for those who seek a pure .Net programmatic way to bind a SSL certificate to a IP endpoint.

Library name (NuGet): **SslCertBinding.Net**

Sources: [GitHub NuGet package sources](https://github.com/segor/SslCertBinding.Net)

Library description:

> SslCertBinding.Net is a library for .NET and Windows and provides a simple API to add, remove or retrieve bindings between a https port and a SSL certificate.

Credits: [Segor](https://github.com/segor)

This library is built upon Win32API calls.

For the usage, have a look to the GitHub NuGet package sources link above, ['Usage' section](https://github.com/segor/SslCertBinding.Net#usage).

Answer (score 2):

The [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364627%28VS.85%29.aspx), Keith Brown's [MSDN column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163531.aspx), and [pinvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net/index.aspx) got me most of the way there.  But getting the PSOCKADDR in the HTTP_SERVICE_CONFIG_SSL_KEY correct was tricky.  I found [Beej's Guide to Network Programming](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/singlepage/bgnet.html) very helpful in figuring out what it *should* look like.  I was able to use the .NET SocketAddress and then copy the bytes to an array that could be marshaled.

```
// serialize the endpoint to a SocketAddress and create an array to hold the values.  Pin the array.
SocketAddress socketAddress = ipEndPoint.Serialize();
byte[] socketBytes = new byte[socketAddress.Size];
GCHandle handleSocketAddress = GCHandle.Alloc(socketBytes, GCHandleType.Pinned);

// Should copy the first 16 bytes (the SocketAddress has a 32 byte buffer, the size will only be 16, which is what the SOCKADDR accepts
for (int i = 0; i < socketAddress.Size; ++i)
{
    socketBytes[i] = socketAddress[i];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but you have to use [the HTTP API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364622(VS.85).aspx) yourself which which there is currently no .NET wrapper, so you must use P/Invoke. Specifically I think you're looking for [HttpSetServiceConfiguration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364503(VS.85).aspx) with the HttpServiceConfigSSLCertInfo config id.