# Enable SSL binding for self-hosted WCF service

Tags: .net, wcf, iis, ssl-certificate

I run a self-hosted WCF service which I want to protect with self-signed SSL certificate. For that to work I need to bind this SSL certificate with certain port. There are couple ways of doing it:

1. According to this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733791.aspx I can use `netsh` and it works but I would like not to have dependencies on the netsh and do everything from the .NET code.
2. So I found the following snippet:

   ```
       using (ServerManager manager = new ServerManager())
       {
           Site site = manager.Sites.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Applications.Cast<Application>().Any());
           Application app = site.Applications.Cast<Application>().First();
           site.Bindings.Add(":*:PORTN", cert.GetCertHash(), store.Name);
           manager.CommitChanges();
       }
   ```

It works, however this required IIS to be installed. Otherwise I'm getting the following exception:

> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID
>   {2B72133B-3F5B-4602-8952-803546CE3344} failed due to the following
>   error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))..

So, question is - is there any way to accomplish this inside managed code, but without having to install IIS?

Comment: there are no direct .net replacements (afaik) for the NETSH requirements. You could just call the NETSH command from a commandline switch into your application /mode=install or something similar.

Comment: If you want to do it in the code you could also look at using P/Invoke to get to NETSH; though if this is simply for installing the application I think Paul's solution is better (and easier).

Comment: I don't want to add this as a requirement for netsh. I need to be able to do several times from inside the application. Basically turning it on and off on-demand.

Comment: I understand not wanting to introduce a dependency, but as far as i know you ultimately need to interact with NETSH with elevated priv's to make the changes you need. so doing it in the app on the fly will require you to do that too.

Comment: @PaulFarry: application is NT Service running under Local System account, so running something under elevated privilege is not a problem

Comment: @sha: If you run your application "As Administrator" you will not need to deal with netsh at all. Elevating privileges with UAC may require user confirmation which is quite big issue when running NT service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the correct answer to my question: [Binding an SSL certificate to a port programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1702596/binding-an-ssl-certificate-to-a-port-programmatically)

Instead of using managed classes like `ServerManager` I would need to rely on P/Invoking native API such as `HttpSetServiceConfiguration`.

Answer (score 0):

> is there any way to accomplish this inside managed code, but without having to install IIS?

Yes, and given that you are running as a service with enough privileges to call NETSH to do the allow and disallow as needed using Process.Start and WaitForExit and can achieve what you need in your question.

The command line syntax http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725882(WS.10).aspx for NETSH allows you to do everything you need.

If you want to figure out all the P/Invoke but it sounds like a lot of extra trouble, but that sounds like academic exercise with more risk of memory leaks and so on.

If you are running on Windows XP and are worried about NETSH not doing what you need, then you can also get Microsoft's HTTPCFG here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364478%28v=vs.85%29.aspx